# Offline iPhone Map with offline routing

Tags: iphone, dictionary, routes, offline

I am developing an iPhone app with :

- offline map
- offline routing

like : mtrip, offMap ...
  http://www.offmaps.com/

I research alot (routeme, navit ...):
  https://github.com/route-me/route-me

But i can not find any frame work or good solution for **Offline Routing**.
Can anyone suggest some idea, framework to use (free or paid) ?

Thanks alot

> > http://www.routino.org is the solution.

Comment: Hi, were you able to get offline routing to work? I have done offline maps with MapBox. Can you please share something on offline routes?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late, but I thought I'd chip in here since no one else has.

You may want to take a look at Waze's offline routing algorithm: http://www.waze.com/wiki/index.php/How_Waze_calculates_routes .  **I must warn you, their  open source implementation is under the *GPL v2*.**